# AngularJS. Could not play audio with source from <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have links to audio files. With ngRepeat I fill them to  
In rendered HTML I gets right code, but it doesn't executes.

**HTML exaample**

```
    <select ng-model="selectedAudioFile" class="audio-dropdown">
        <option ng-repeat="audioFile in audioFiles" value="{{audioFile.url}}">{{ audioFile.url}}</option>
    </select>

     <audio id="audioNg2">
        <source src="{{selectedAudioFile}}"></source>
     </audio>

     <button ng-click="playNg2()">Play NG2</button>
```

Detailed on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paka/LqkwT/

First two buttons is working and the last one with angular-repeat and  doest'n play sounds.
Do you have any ieda why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.load()` if you change the `src` on and `<audio/>` element.

```
$scope.playNg2 = function () {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audioNg2");
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
};
```

With that being said, you are better off creating a directive since dom manipulation inside of a controller is against angular's ideals.

*Some other notes*

use [`ng-options`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) instead of `ng-repeat` when dealing with select lists.

```
<select ng-model="selectedAudioFile" class="audio-dropdown" ng-options="audio.url as audio.url for audio in audioFiles">
</select>
```

Place your methods on your scope instead of having them in the global scope.

Comment: thanks for comment and advises @Mark. I use yours ng-options and .load() here http://jsfiddle.net/paka/LqkwT/7/ but it does not works

Comment: sorry, added function to scope and everything is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: In my case it works even withoy load(), but I execute play() in controller function of a component.

Answer (score 3):

Simply on `ng-change` in `select` element, execute a function that contains:

```
var audio = new Audio("audio.src || audio.url");
audio.play();
```

where `audio.src` or `aurio.url` is a reference to the location of the file locally or at a URL address. It is the value of the `ng-model` of the `select` element.